# Azure CICD - common steps in one place

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I need help with Azure CICD configuration. Now it looks in that

```yaml
trigger:
 branches:
    include:
      - master
      - main
      - development

stages:
  - stage: UberStage
    jobs:
      - job: SuperJob
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - script: |
            command1
            command2
            command3
            command4
            other_command
          displayName: 'Super description'

      - job: MegaJob
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - script: |
            command1
            command2
            command3
            command4
            other_command_2
          displayName: 'Mega description'

      - job: UberJob
        pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - script: |
            command1
            command2
            command3
            command4
            other_command_3
          displayName: 'Uber description'
```

As you see there is few common parts in all jobs like pool and first few steps.
Is it possible in Azure CICD yaml keep DRY rule and do not duplicate common parts?
Also is it possible to setup trigger to run in all branches and specific jobs to run only on main/master?

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards
Draqun

Answer (score 0):

You need to take look on

- [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) to apply dry

It will allow you to define template:

```yaml
# File: simple-param.yml
parameters:
- name: yesNo # name of the parameter; required
  type: boolean # data type of the parameter; required
  default: false

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.yesNo }}
```

and the use it

```yaml
# File: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: simple-param.yml
  parameters:
      yesNo: false # set to a non-boolean value to have the build fail
```

- [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run specific jobs for specific branch

```yaml
variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - script: echo $(isMain)
```

Comment: Can you provide example how to do it? Microsoft does not know how to create good documentation.